# jQueryUI load page into DIV and into modal dialog

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm attempting to load a page into a a modal DIV but seem to be missing something (probably blatantly obvious!). Here's what I  have.

**The Problem**
The pages don't load into the div, instead clicking on the links just goes straight to the page

In my **`<head>`** section

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/load_modal.js"></script>
```

My load_modal.js script looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        buttons: {
                "Close": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $(".modal").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#dialog").html("");
        $("#dialog").dialog("option", "title", "Loading...").dialog("open");
        $("#dialog").load(this.href, function() {
            $(this).dialog("option", "title", $(this).find("h2").text());
            //$(this).find("h1").remove();
        });
    });
})
```

And the links I'm trying to put into the modal div look like this

```
<div id="dialog"></div>
<a class="modal" href="/privacy.html">privacy policy</a>
```

**Things I've Tried**

- Different versions of jQuery and jQuery UI
- Removing all code except for event.preventDefault(); -- this should keep the link from even loading but the page still loads!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading your page in an iframe using jQuery UI:

```
$(".modal").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //console.log('click'); TO CHECK IF CLICK IS DETECTED
    var iframe = $('<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="600" height="400"></iframe>');
    var dialog = $("<div></div>").append(iframe).appendTo("body").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    width: "auto",
    height: "auto",
    close: function () {
        iframe.attr("src", "");
        }
});
    var src = $(this).attr("href");
    iframe.attr({
        src: src
    });
    dialog.dialog("option", "title", "Your Title...").dialog("open");
});
```

PS: This works on any link with the class modal.

Comment: Same as above. It's like jQuery isn't even loading but I do have it as the first library loaded through the Google hosted URL.

Comment: This script works fine on several websites I own... If you put "console.log('click');", you see the click in the log? If not, jquery is not loaded...

Comment: Nothing shows up in the log. I can't figure out why jQuery isn't loading. It's the first script linked in my head section and I've verified that by viewing the source and clicking on the URL to the Google-hosted instance of it, that it loads the library. So what am I missing?

Comment: Okay so I've built a skeleton page that includes only jquery, jqueryui, and my custom css. Doing this and wrapping your script in a document.ready statement works. So now I have to figure out if there's a processing order error on my page somewhere... right?

Comment: Found the problem. Apparently another one of my scripts had a syntax error. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First add some CSS into your  to make the modal box look right:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

Then, slightly modify your load_modal.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    buttons: {
            "Close": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });


$(".modal").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#dialog").html("");
    $("#dialog").dialog("option", "title", "Loading...").dialog("open");
    $("#dialog").load(this.href, function() {
        $(this).dialog("option", "title", $(this).find("h2").text());
        //$(this).find("h1").remove();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I already have a customized jQuery UI css file linked. See update to original post. Wrapping the entire function in the document.ready() didn't do anything. The link still just opens the page as if jQuery weren't even being processed.

Comment: In your original load_modal.js, you have 4 "{" brackets.  You close them all in the top half.  The bottom half has 2 "{" brackets, but 3 "}".  That showed up right away in my Safari web inspector.  In my solution, I wrap both functions with the document.ready().  I think your problem may be related to those brackets.

Comment: I didn't catch the brackets in my original. Thanks for that. I replaced my entire load_modal.js with your script and it's still exhibiting the same behavior.

Comment: The symptom would also occur if your <head> link didn't actually load the load_modal.js file.  Did you confirm that it is in the /js/ directory?  If it's in a child folder you may need to go with src="js/load_modal.js" (remove the leading slash before /js/load_modal.js).

Comment: It loaded it. I could view the source and click on the path to it and it opened.